# unlink() Function invalid argument

Tags: php, unlink

I have a file with directory: `PDF\9783790820874-c1.pdf`
I would like to delete this file with `unlink()` funciton. But it seems like not working if I set the directory into a variable and unlink it.
For example:

```
$FileToDelete = "PDF\9783790820874-c1.pdf";
unlink($FileToDelete);
```

The code is logic isn't it? but why when I execute it, it show me error message:

```
Warning: unlink(PDF\9783790820874-c1.pdf ): Invalid argument on line 36
```

I have to save file directory into a variable to work well with my program, is there any way to solve it?

Comment: Couldn't reproduce the error! Try to change the `\ ` to `/`

Comment: error is due to \ in file name.

Comment: Trying to think what `\9` is... either way, if you want to use backslashes, you need to either escape it with another backslash, or use single quotes for the string.

Comment: But the code work well if I directly write the argument with the directory path like: `unlink('PDF\9783790820874-c1.pdf');` and I try to change "\" to "/", doesn't work too @Rizier123

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your backslash is being interpreted as an Escape Sequence.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Either change it to a forward slash (which does work for paths on Windows):

```
$FileToDelete = "PDF/9783790820874-c1.pdf";
```

Or use single quotes:

```
$FileToDelete = 'PDF\9783790820874-c1.pdf';
```

Or just escape the backslash:

```
$FileToDelete = "PDF\\9783790820874-c1.pdf";
```

Comment: It's a good habit to use single quotes anyway, unless PHP needs to process something inside. I think you have the wrong link though, that one is for regex. This is probably what you wanted http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Comment: I have 2 variables, which are `$str1 = "PDF\\9783790820874-c1.pdf" ` and `str2 = $DataField[$j].'\\'.$DataField[$j+1];`, both will echo the same result: `PDF\9783790820874-c1.pdf`, but when I use funtion `unlink($str1)` and `unlink($str2)`, only the one with `$str1` as argument will works. Why? Please Help @JoeCoder

Comment: Clearly `str1` and `str2` aren't actually the same, or else they'd work the same. I have no idea what is in your `$DataField` array so I can't help you debug `str2`. But if `str1` works then your problem is solved right?

Comment: Nope, `$str1` only for testing purpose. Actually I use `$DataField[]` to store the directory of file and name of file, then I have to use it to get the them for delete purpose. Both `$str1` and `$str2` echo the exactly same result, but why `$str2` doesn't work? @JoeCoder

Answer (score 2):

I presume you are on Windows based on the backslash path separator.

I think the problem is due to escaping backslash causing problems, try:

```
$FileToDelete = "PDF\\9783790820874-c1.pdf";
unlink($FileToDelete);
```

Hopefully that will fix it for you.

Remember that '' and "" behave differently in relation to escaping within the string. So while 'a\b.pdf' might work "a\b.pdf" could mean something completely different (where a and b are [some string]).