# Always get invalid argument when unlink() file from public directory

Tags: php, unlink

I use laravel 5.4, I dont really know what exacly causing this error .

> unlink(C:\xampp5.6\htdocs\sp2hp\public/files/admin/perkara/file_159f459cb9307a.sql
>   ): Invalid argument

even I've change with single quote or backslah or any of this asnwer from [unlink() Function invalid argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29037941/unlink-function-invalid-argument)
it's still not working

Here's my code

```
if (!empty($x->file)) {
   unlink(public_path('/files/admin/perkara/'.$x->file));   
}
```

[image]

[image: From begining its show double quote and]

any idea ?

Comment: check carefully the path ... sometime **/** and sometimes \ which is wrong

Comment: can you do an echo of public_path('/files/admin/perkara/'.$x->file) and show us the result ? i'm sure it's there the answer

Comment: echo your url first, and change this unlink(public_path('files/admin/perkara/'.$x->file));

Comment: @SimosFasouliotis it is echoed in error message

Comment: @SimosFasouliotis sure result echo same in error message the different is double quote, I've edited the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to check your directory then delete items from it or deleted the directory in public path

```
   /** @var $files_in_directory => check if directory is empty */
   $files_in_directory = scandir(public_path('/files/admin/perkara/'));
   $items_count = count($files_in_directory);
   /** The first two items are . and .. => so we should count from 2 */
   if ($items_count <= 2) {
      /** Remove User Directory from public directory */
      File::deleteDirectory(public_path('/files/admin/perkara/'.$x->file));
   }
```

Comment: the result still same error. can u see at ending ``.sql``` ? there ```space``` beetwen ```.sql``` and ```)```

Comment: try this : Storage::Delete(public_path('/files/admin/perkara/'.$x->file))

Answer (score 0):

`public_path()` doesn't have any parameters in Laravel 5.4 (see official [public_path](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-public-path)). And try removing first slash and apply a second slash after `perkara/`.

```
unlink(public_path() . 'files/admin/perkara//' . $x->file);
```

Comment: Yes, sorry I looked into 5.5.